# Determining If Something Is A Set Is A Ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I had a question that I don't understand. I was looking through my abstract algebra textbook and I did a couple problem and I got most of the the problems right except for this one:
$$R = {(a + b\sqrt[3]{3}}) :a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$$

It might be a dumb question but why is this not a ring?

$(R, +)$ is an abelian group. 
I double checked and saw that there exist a zero element $0_R\in R$

There exists an inverse such that $a + (-a) = 0_R$

It's associative with the operation +.

In terms of multiplication, it looks like it's associative and distributive as well.

Hints?

Comment: If you square $\sqrt[3]{3}$ can you write the result in the form $a+b\sqrt[3]{3}$?

Comment: Ah, so it's not closed under multiplication. Thank you.